# How do I change the appearance of nodes in a Tree control in Flex using an extended TreeItemRenderer?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm using a tree control that I want to customize. The data items in the tree's `dataProvider` have a property `name` that should be used for labeling the node, and a property `type` that should be used to select one of several embedded images for use as an icon. The simplest way to do this is by using the `labelField` and `iconFunction` properties.

However, I wanted to get started with item renderers and open the door for adding more complex customization later, so I tried making my own item renderer. I extended the `TreeItemRenderer` class as follows and used it in my tree control:

```
class DirectoryItemRenderer extends TreeItemRenderer
{
  [Embed("assets/directory/DefaultIcon.png")]
  private static var _DEFAULT_ICON:Class;

  // ... some more icons ...

  override public function set data(value:Object):void
  {
    super.data = value; // let the base class take care of everything I didn't think of
    if (value is Node) { // only handle the data if it's our own node class
      switch ((value as Node).type) {
        // ... some case clauses ...
        default:
          this._vSetIcon(_DEFAULT_ICON);
      }
      this.label.text = (value as Node).name;
    }
  }

  private function _vSetIcon(icon:Class):void
  {
    if (null != this.icon && this.contains(this.icon)) {
      this.removeChild(this.icon);
    }
    this.icon = new icon();
    this.addChild(this.icon);
    this.invalidateDisplayList();
  }
}
```

This code has no effect whatsoever, icon and label in the tree control remain at their defaults. Using `trace()`, I verified that my code is actually executed. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the base `mx.controls.treeClasses.TreeItemRenderer` class, I see that in the `updateDisplayList` function the renderer gets it's `icon` and `disclosureIcon` classes from `_listData:TeeListData`.  Instead of overriding the `updateDisplayList` function, try modifying the `icon` and `disclosureIcon` classes of the renderer's private `_listData` instance in your `_vSetIcon` method using the public accessors, like so:

```
private function _vSetIcon(icon:Class, disclosureIcon:Class = null):void
{
    var tmpListData:TreeListData;   

    if (disclosureIcon == null) disclosureIcon = icon;

    tmpListData = this.listData;
    tmpListData.icon = icon;
    tmpListData.disclosureIcon = disclosureIcon;

    this.listData = tmpListData;
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is some clarification on the difference between `data` and `listData`.  You'll have to excuse my omission of package names but I'm editing from my phone so its tough to look them up and I don't know the package names off the top of my head.  `data` is defined in the context of a `TreeItemRenderer` in the `IDataRenderer` interface. You create a data renderer by implementing this interface and defining a public property `data`, which in this case is set by the parent control and contains some data and meta-data  from the `dataProvider` to be rendered by the data renderer class.

`listData` is defined in the `IDropInListItemRenderer` interface as a property of type `BaseListData` and is realized in the `TreeItemRenderer` class as a property `TreeListData`. It differs from the `data` property in that it contains meta-data that describes the `TreeListRenderer` itself (icon, indent, open) as well as (I believe, I'll have to double check this later) a reference to the data item being rendered.  I gather that It's used by the the `TreeItemRenderer` and I would imagine the parent list control for display update and sizing purposes. Someone is free to correct or add onto that if I'm incorrect or missed something, I'm going of what I remember drom the code.

In this case, you wanted to use meta-data from the data set from the data provider to modify data that determines the display of the renderer, so you would need to modify both.

I think the real confusion here however came from the fact that you extended the `TreeItemRenderer` class then tried to override functionality on the component in a manner the original developer didn't intend for someone to do, hence the unexpected results.  If your goal is education and not ease of implementation you would probably be better served by extending the `UIComponent` class and using the `TreeItemRenderer` code as a reference to create a class that implements the same interfaces.  That would be a real dive into the pool of custom component development.

Comment: I don'r really get the difference between `listData` and `data`, i. e. when to use what, do you?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably try something simple, as in [this example](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_do_I_create_a_Tree_itemRenderer_-62.html) from the Adobe Cookbooks.  I notice that they override `updateDisplayList`, which may have something to do with your problems.

There's [another example](http://macmartine.com/blog/2006/04/extending_treeitemrenderer_to.html) (for Flex 2, but looks applicable to Flex 3) that shows how to manage the default icons.  It looks like you'll want to manage the icon yourself, setting the default icon styles to null, instead of trying to manipulate the superclass's icon property.

**Update** -- Looking at the source for TreeItemRenderer, `commitProperties` has the following before checking the data and setting up the icon and label:

```
if (icon)
{
    removeChild(DisplayObject(icon));
    icon = null;
}
```

Also, it looks like the setter for `data` calls `invalidateProperties`.  Hence, your icon is wiped out when the framework gets around to calling `commitProperties`.

Comment: I had seen the second example before. My problem is that it works around what I'm interested in. For example, I can't see why they don't work with `icon`, as this must be still lurking around somewhere in the superclass. It's probably `null` by virtue of having set the style properties, but there must be two children now that can hold an icon. Guess I have to go read source...

Comment: I'm now guessing the original `updateDisplayList` sets the icon, so when I set it in `set data`, it got rewritten afterwards.